# Listen to iOS Capacitor notifications in Ionic React

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm working with Ionic framework in React. I've created an iOS app from it using the Capacitor. Now in the Capacitor app, in `AppDelegate` when `application(_:open:options:)` is called, capacitor calls a `handlerOpenUrl(_:_:)` method which in turn posts the `notifications`.

```
  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return CAPBridge.handleOpenUrl(url, options)
  }

  public static func handleOpenUrl(_ url: URL, _ options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(CAPNotifications.URLOpen.name()), object: [
      "url": url,
      "options": options
    ])
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.CDVPluginHandleOpenURL, object: url)
    CAPBridge.lastUrl = url
    return true
  }
```

Now, I want to listen to these `notifications` in my ionic react codebase so I can show the `url` and `options` on the UI.

I couldn't find any relevant content on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Capacitor notification use [App plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app)

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { App } = Plugins;

App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
  console.log('App opened',  data.url, data.options);
});
```